# With Selenium/Python How to restrict element search on a paticular column of a webtable

Tags: python, selenium, html-table

I'm currently working with Selenium and Python to create a script that helps with booking free spots on a website for internships so you don't have to check it all the time.

My Question is how can you tell selenium to only search in a particular column for a text element of a webtable? I want it to search 1st column to 3rd column as a kind of prioritization and later click each positive result on the way.
I know it works for rows but I can't wrap my head around how to make it work for columns. Below I tried to combine the general Xpath expression of my target element and an general expression for the first column so selenium would go through them 1 by 1. Could that work somehow? This is what I tried for the third column:

```
i = range(8,28)

xpath = f'//*[starts-with(text(),"1/)"]/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/div/table/tbody /tr{i}/td[10]/img'


for i in range (8,28):


    T3 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath')
    print(len(T3))
```

this gives me 0 results unfortunately. Any help is much appreciated!
(the condition on which the search is satisfied and the element should be clicked is having available spaces. On the website a text element indicates avaialble placed: number of available places/number of total places so p.e. "1/3". I tried it via search for the text element "1/" where one place is available. Not ideal since I want all numbers >=1 to be included but have no clue how. Maybe someone also knows this.
[image: Screenshot of the Website]

Comment: could you please explain the condition on which if it satisfies then you should click

Comment: tr[position()<20] while go from 1-20.

Comment: @SonaliDas I updated the description

Comment: @ArundeepChohan which part does your solution replace? Part of the xpath ?

Comment: It replaces part of the xpath